# Iteratively calculate the power set of a set or vector

Tags: c++, set, powerset

While there are plenty of examples on how to generate the actual power set of a set, I can't find anything about iteratively (as in `std::iterator`) generating the power set. The reason why I would appreciate such an algorithm is the size of my base set. As the power set of a n-element set has 2^n elements, I would quickly run out of memory when actually computing the set. So, is there any way to create an iterator for the power set of a given set? Is it even possible?

- If it would be easier, an iterator that creates sets of `int`s would be fine - I could use them as indices for the actual set/vector.
- As I actually work on a `std::vector`, random access would be possible if neccessary

Comment: Use a bitset of `n` bits, initialized to zeros. On each step, add 1 with carry, as if the bitset represented an `n`-bit integer. Use the resulting pattern of zeros and ones to determine which elements belong to the current subset. Repeat until the bitset reaches all ones. If `n <= 64` (or whatever is the largest integer available on your platform), then you can use an actual integer variable in place of a bitset.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik - Is that common knowledge on how to handle this issue, i.e. was I not searching hard enough? I would happily accept this as the answer if you added it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `for_each_combination` from [Combinations and Permutations](http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) one can easily iterate through all members of the power set of a `std::vector<AnyType>`.  For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "../combinations/combinations"

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::size_t num_visits = 0;
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k <= v.size(); ++k)
        for_each_combination(v.begin(), v.begin()+k, v.end(),
            [&](auto first, auto last)
            {
                std::cout << '{';
                if (first != last)
                {
                    std::cout << *first;
                    for (++first; first != last; ++first)
                        std::cout << ", " << *first;
                }
                std::cout << "}\n";
                ++num_visits;
                return false;
            });
    std::cout << "num_visits = " << num_visits << '\n';
}
```

This visits each power set member of this `vector`, and executes the functor, which simply counts the number of visits and prints out the current power set:

```
{}
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{5}
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{1, 4}
{1, 5}
{2, 3}
{2, 4}
{2, 5}
{3, 4}
{3, 5}
{4, 5}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 4}
{1, 2, 5}
{1, 3, 4}
{1, 3, 5}
{1, 4, 5}
{2, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 5}
{2, 4, 5}
{3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 5}
{1, 2, 4, 5}
{1, 3, 4, 5}
{2, 3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
num_visits = 32
```

The syntax I've used above is C++14.  If you have C++11, you will need to change:

```
[&](auto first, auto last)
```

to:

```
[&](std::vector<int>::const_iterator first, std::vector<int>::const_iterator last)
```

And if you are in C++98/03, you will have to write a functor or function to replace the lambda.

The `for_each_combination` function allocates no extra storage.  This is all done by swapping members of the `vector` into the range `[v.begin(), v.begin()+k)`.  At the end of each call to `for_each_combination` the vector is left in its original state.

If for some reason you want to "exit" the `for_each_combination` early, simply return `true` instead of `false`.