# Generating powesets of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, powerset

I am currently trying to write a function which will allow me to create the powerset of a vector. I currently have a vector of objects and an empty vector of vectors. I looked around online, and found [a recursive algorithm](http://www.programminglogic.com/powerset-algorithm-in-c/), but was unable to get it to work in my case.

Algorithm:

```
void Game::PowersetRec(vector <Die> & s, int k, int m, int n) {
    // Recursively builds a vector which is the powerset of the input vector
    if (m <= n) {
        s[k+1].pips = m ;
        powerset.push_back(s) ;
        PowersetRec(s, k+1, m+1, n) ; /* with m */
        PowersetRec(s, k, m+1, n) ; /*  without m */
    }
}
```

.

```
PowersetRec(rolledDice, 0, rolledDice[0].pips, rolledDice[rolledDice.size() - 1].pips);
```

`powerset` is my vector of vectors and `rolledDice` is a vector of `Die` objects which have a `pips` attribute (which is an integer).

When I print out powerset I get this (sample):

```
1, 1, 4, 6, 4, 6
1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 6
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Which makes sense to me given the algorithm, but isn't the powerset, meaning I don't know how the original algorithm worked.

Edit: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984609/iteratively-calculate-the-power-set-of-a-set-or-vector) Seems useful, but I cannot get the code listed (combinations) to compile in GCC.

Comment: I am flagging this because, although you weren't specifically asking for an iterative method, this question seems to be a duplicate of this question: www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25984609/

Comment: I cannot get the code listed there to work, the combinations code doesn't even compile for me (gcc).

Comment: It looks like that code relies heavily on C++11 which isn't an option for me, and implementing all the compatibility patches seems more complex than simply making a new function. It doesn't need to be particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer the question via: [the different combinations of a vector's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331229/the-different-combinations-of-a-vectors-values)

I simply changed char to my die object.

Edit: Full code below.

```
void Game::PowersetGen(vector <Die> & v) {
for (int counter = 1; counter < (1 << v.size()); ++counter) {
        vector <Die> combination;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (counter & (1 << i))
                combination.push_back(v[i]);
        }

        powerset.push_back(combination);
    }
}
```

Simple clarifying edit: `<Die>` is just the name of the object in my vector, ideally this function would be templated to use any data type.

Comment: Could you post the solution?